# How to release tracked entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Hopefully the following code snippet clear enough to explain the problem. `_db` is an instance of `DbContext`.

```
// this scenario is only for learning purpose
Author a = _db.Authors.Find(1831);
int id = a.AuthorId;
a = null;

Author stub = new Author { AuthorId = id };
_db.Remove(stub);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

The code above produces

> 'The instance of entity type 'Author' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'AuthorId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'

## Question

How to free `a` from being tracked?

Comment: `_db.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Detached`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to do this, but I find this the most simple since you're trying to detach a specific entity.

```
_db.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Detached
```

As a plus it doesn't require changing any other code, including however you fetched the entity itself.

This one line makes it very clear of the intent.  It also allows the following:

1. Fetch an entity, or list of entities
2. Do various types of work
3. Detach an entity

I dislike the idea of changing existing queries on a `DbContext` when all I want to do is detach something.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `AsNoTracking()`.
_db.Authors.AsNoTracking().Where(a => a.AuthorId == 1831).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 3):

You should use `AsNoTracking` option while querying for a.

e.g.  Below query gets all blog items but if you try to delete them you should not get any error.

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToList();
```

You can set `AsNoTracking` either on query or it can also be set on the context object as shown below:

```
context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

var blogs = context.Blogs.ToList();
```

This should help you to resolve this.

Refer [this MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

From EF Core 5, you can use [ChangeTracker.Clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.clear) :

> Stops tracking all currently tracked entities.

The documentation recommends to use this method instead of manually detached all entities :

> This method should always be preferred over detaching every tracked entity. Detaching entities is a slow process that may have side effects. This method is much more efficient at clearing all tracked entities from the context.

---

Also, the documentation recommends the alternative, to create a new DbContext for each operation :

> DbContext is designed to have a short lifetime where a new instance is created for each unit-of-work. This manner means all tracked entities are discarded when the context is disposed at the end of each unit-of-work. However, clearing all tracked entities using this method may be useful in situations where creating a new context instance is not practical.